# Binary Ones Complement Operator (~) Not working properly (or I don't know how to use it)

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit, bitwise-operators

I have this line of code:

```
System.out.println("Flipped byte: " + ((~ Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(byteRepresentation[8], 2), 2)) & 0xFF));
```

The fact that bytes are signed is getting in my way here. byteRepresentation is an array of bytes (java byte primitive). When byteRepresentation[8] is a positive nuber (+) it works properly, however when byteRepresentation[8] is a negative number (-) it just removes the minus (making the result positive) and substracts 1.

I'm looking for a way to for example make -127 become 0, -126 become 1 and so on.

Comment: -127 becomes 0 and -126 becomes 1? That's not the 2complement representation java uses. In java the byte `0xFF` represents -1 and `0x00` represents 0. If you negate a 2 complement number the effect you described is **expected**, see http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~hawkes/cda3101lects/chap4/negation.html

Comment: I see... I should avoid using things I don't completely understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavoir is right. `~` just flips all the bits and then it will be interpreted as the [twos complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

You just want to add +127 to your numbers, to get the desired behavoir (-127 -> 0, -126 -> 1)

### An Example

~(1) -> ~(00000001) -> 11111110 -> -2

> System.out.println(~1); // -2

~(-1) -| ~(11111111) -> 00000000 -> 0

> System.out.println(~-1); // 0